# function template overload with rvaule reference as argument does not work?

Tags: c++, c++17

The function template with && as argument seems cannot be overloaded, when input is not rvalue. See [here](https://godbolt.org/z/Gv3YoYEWW) as example:

```cpp
template<typename A, typename B>
void test_tp_func(A&& a, B&& b)
{
    std::cout<<"tp1(" << a << "," << b << ")\n";
}
template<typename A>
void test_tp_func(A&& a, int&& b)
{
    std::cout<<"tp2(" << a << "," << b << ")\n";
}
int main()
{
    test_tp_func(1, 2);
    int i{10};
    const int& ir = i;
    test_tp_func(2, ir);
    test_tp_func(2, std::move(i));
}
```

The output is:

```
tp2(1,2)
tp1(2,10)
tp2(2,10)
```

We can see the `test_tp_func(2, ir);` is not using the overload at all. How can I make sure it use the `test_tp_func(A&& a, int&& b)`? One way is to add enable_if_t to disable the original template when B is int. However, the original template `test_tp_func(A&& a, B&& b)` is defined in a file that is not in my control.

updated the example to actually use const&

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How can you choose the rvalue overload? It would help if the argument was an [rvalue](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/value_category) which `i` is not.

It's not a prvalue (it's a named variable) and it isn't an xvalue either.

If you just want to intercept the case where `B = int`, why not just make the argument type `int`? Using `int&&` will only match rvalues by definition.

As discussed in comments, you can't simply replace the forwarding reference  `B&&` with an rvalue reference `int&&` (or any other concrete type in place of `int`) because forwarding references get special treatment during argument deduction (see [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/template_argument_deduction) and search for "forwarding reference", it's a special case).

You need two overloads: the const ref `const int&`, and the rvalue ref `int&&`, to cover the same cases as the original forwarding reference.

Comment: Another option would be to create `int&`, `const int&` and `int&&` overloads - if some manipulation of the passed argument is wanted in the non-`const` cases.

Comment: the int is just an example. The real world case, B can be a big class, copy is expensive for it. pass by value is not acceptable. It should either by const& or &&

Comment: Absolutely true. I _suspect_ here the OP just performed a manual substitution, without realising the difference between an rvalue reference and a forwarding reference.

Comment: In that case you do need to write both `&&` rvalue reference and `const&` const ref overloads. They do different things, and match different arguments. The `B&&` forwarding reference gets special treatment during argument deduction to handle both.

Comment: seems like so. Which is kind of annoying. I thought since B&& can handle const B& and B&& then the int&& should be use to overload both const int& and int&&. But unfortunately it does not. Any explanation here?

Comment: Citation added. The forwarding reference gets special treatment so you don't have to do this for template params - but you still need to match non-template parameters normally.